# Taking minimum value of neighboring cells

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function that takes receives some matrix[N][M] (N and M are defined at the beginning and they're both always 3), two integers and returns the smallest value of neighboring cells (horizontally, vertically and diagonally) to that specific (y,x) cell  (The function is part of a larger code that takes specific (y,x)s and not any (y,x). it is called in some specific cases) in a 2D array - Minimum(int mat[N][M], int y, int x).

Say for example I have the 2D array and I'm looking specifically at the 0,0 element

1  10  9

18  9  10

19 10 8

I want that cell to change to 9 since its the smallest value of the neighboring cells (the cell itself doesn't matter if it's the minimum of them all or not) so the array becomes

9  10  9

18  9  10

19 10 8

What I tried: First I went over each neighboring cell. After that, I mainly tried storing the value of that neighboring cell in some other variable

```
tmp=mat[y+i][x+j]
```

that changes in every iteration and then add some if condition after it which takes the minimum value to the `mat[y][x]=mat[y+i][x+j]` cell. I tried a lot of conditions and none worked.

Another thing I thought of and tried implementing was adding a 1D array that stores the values of the all the neighboring cells (if there are less than the size of the array - store 0) and then checking the minimum between every two cells excluding the 0s. The code got scrambled and I got lost on where I would put the loop for that array.

I went over the neighboring cells of some specific y,x cell in the following way:

```
Min(int mat[N][M], int y, int x)
{
    for(i=-1;i<=1;i++)
    {
        if((y+i>=0) && (y+i<=N))
        {
            for(j=-1;j<=1;j++)
            {
                if((x+j>=0) && (x+j<=M))
                {
                    if((x+i != 0) && (y+j != 0))
                    {
                        /*CONDITION TO TAKE MINIMUM*/    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In the usual sense of `array[N][M]`, and where the meaning of `y` is usually row and `x` is column, you seem to be comparing the indexing limits with the wrong dimension. I would expect `y` to be associated with `N`, and `x` with `M`.

Comment: I can flip the names then y would be representing rows and x columns. that's no problem. I'll update my code.

Comment: It is a problem in the future if the matrix is not square.

Comment: I'm more used to think of xs as rows. I changed the code if it's easier to understand.

Comment: Start with `int minval = mat[0][0];` and where `/*CONDITION TO TAKE MINIMUM*/` you can have `if(minval > mat[y+j][x+i]) { minval = mat[y+j][x+i];}`

Comment: First off thanks for the help. Second, you init minval to mat[0][0] according to my specific example? In general you mean minval=mat[x][y]?

Comment: Oh, yes sorry that's right.

Comment: You can init `minval` with some value that is bigger than all elements, like 1000000

Comment: you probably want to init minval to `INT_MAX`  found in  `limits.h`

Comment: @Pavel only worth it with `minval = INT_MAX;` but using an actual element value is more maintainable.

Comment: By my example, this wouldn't work because the cell will stay 1 (I want to changed to the minimum value of the cells surrounding it horizontally, vertically and diagonally. Hence it changes to 9)

Comment: Then use `minval = INT_MAX;`. Sorry, didn;t read the code fragment properly.

Comment: No idea what that is to be honest. I suppose it's another library. I can't use other than stdio.h

Comment: `INT_MAX` is in `limits.h` but if you are not allowed, just use the largest number you will ever get in the array.

Comment: I'm a little confused. How would what you suggested change the value of mat[y][x]?

Comment: Do you want to consider the `[y][x]` cell?

Comment: the [y][x] cell is what I want to change to the minimum of the neighboring cells. In the example the [y][x] cell is is the [0][0] cell and I want to change its value from 1 (mat[0][0]=1) to 9 (mat[0][0]=9 since it's the minimum cell value of [0][0]'s closest neighbors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `matr[N][M]` it doesn't have elements like `matr[?][M]` and `matr[N][?]` because numeration is from `0` to `N-1` (or `M-1`). So you should change condition `y+i<=N` to `y+i<N` and `x+j<=M` to `x+j<M`.

2) To check that you aren't looking at the cell `[y][x]` itself you should check `if(!(i == 0 && j == 0))` or, equivalent, `if(i != 0 || j != 0)` instead of `if(x+i != 0 && y+j != 0)`

3) To find minimum first make `int min = INT_MAX;` at beginning of the function. The *condition to take minimum* will be

```
if (mat[y+i][x+j] < min)
    min = mat[y+i][x+j];
```

4) To write the minimum to the cell `[y][x]`, use `matr[y][x] = Min(matr, y, x);` in main function or where you want

---

Alternatively you can walk through all possible cells `[i][j]` such a way:

```
int u = max(0, y - 1), d = min(y + 1, N - 1);
int l = max(0, x - 1), r = min(x + 1, M - 1);
for (i = d; i <= u; i++)
    for (j = l; j <= r; j++)
        if (i != y || j != x)
            if (mat[i][j] < min)
                min = mat[i][j];
return min;
```

Comment: A couple of questions: why not use if(x+i != 0 && y+j != 0)? This condition guarantees that I'm looking at a neighbor and not the cell itself. Also, I'm not allowed to work with other libraries. And how would this all change the value of mat[y][x]? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: You doesn't want to look at the cell itself? I edited answer (2nd item)

Comment: No. Check out the example above I edited it to what I have before and what I want after. I hope that would make what I'm saying clear.

Comment: In the example I saw that you doesn't want to consider the `[y][x]` cell while finding minimum. In 2nd item at my answer I wrote how to do it

Comment: I want the minimum of the closet cells around [y][x] and then that minimum to store in mat[y][x]